# Mean across multiple date

Tags: r, date, mean

I have a large data with some columns that are dates. I would like to make the average of day 1 of January of the year '97 with the average of day 1 of January of '98 and so on. My data starts from 01-01-1997 to 31-12-2014. I would like to get an "average" year of GPP data. Can you help me, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(MONTH, DAY) %>%
  summarize(GPP = mean(GPP))

df2
#> # A tibble: 365 x 3
#> # Groups:   MONTH [12]
#> MONTH   DAY   GPP
#> <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1 0.611
#> 2     1     2 0.330
#> 3     1     3 0.676
#> 4     1     4 0.553
#> 5     1     5 0.460
#> 6     1     6 0.544
#> 7     1     7 0.597
#> 8     1     8 0.806
#> 9     1     9 0.315
#> 10     1    10 0.109
#> # ... with 355 more rows
```

---

**Data Used**

Note that we do not have your data, so I made a reproducible example which should match the structure of the data frame pictured in the OP

```r
m_lens <- c(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(YEAR  = rep(1997:1999, each = 365),
                 DAY   = rep(unlist(sapply(m_lens, seq_len)), 3),
                 MONTH = rep(rep(1:12, times = m_lens), 3),
                 GPP   = runif(365 * 3))

head(df)
#>   YEAR DAY MONTH       GPP
#> 1 1997   1     1 0.2655087
#> 2 1997   2     1 0.3721239
#> 3 1997   3     1 0.5728534
#> 4 1997   4     1 0.9082078
#> 5 1997   5     1 0.2016819
#> 6 1997   6     1 0.8983897
...
```

Comment: My dataframe starts from 1997 to 2014. So I have to calculate the mean of the value of GPP on 01-01-1997 with the value of GPP of 01-01-1998 and so on. I have to use this data to create seasonal line plot with a one single line (mean year of the total year) per months in x axis.

Comment: @Vin, yes - this code does exactly that. My example data was just to demonstrate the code. Obviously you use your own data here. Ignore the bit at the bottom and just use the top code, substituting `df` for whatever your data frame is called.

Comment: ok, but how I can use the output after that function. I'm so sorry for the disturbance

Comment: You need to store it to a variable. See my update.